# Jquery Mobile: Embed external HTML file without iframe

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I load a external html page in a div?

```
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
   <!--Load nav.html here-->
  </div> 
...
```

I have tried with following code but it doesn't function.

```
$( "#myPanel" ).load( "nav.html" );
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/N6xTrvLHWdOMG9Lq?open=lib%2Findex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel is expecting some markup as content, not a whole HTML page.

This will load Your navigation `listview` inside the `panel`:

```
$(document).on('panelcreate', '#myPanel', function () {
    $(this).children(".ui-panel-inner").load("nav.html ul", function() {
        $(this).enhanceWithin().trigger("updatelayout");
    });      
});
```

The full-width `listview` is requiring some additional CSS:

```
/* The left reveal panel shadow is 5px inset and blurred by 5px */
.ui-panel-display-reveal.ui-panel-position-left .ui-listview {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To test Your navigation menu and see if it looks as intended, You may design it directly inside the `panel`. To allow the framework to create the `panelInner`, simply put somewhat inside the `panel div`, i.e. a placeholder `div` or, as said, even better the static version of Your navigation menu. Thus, it will be then correctly replaced by Your external version.

In one word, instead of `<!--Load nav.html here-->` write `<div>...</div>`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've used it in my example. But the content of "nav.html" is still not shown. What am I doing wrong?
Here the current example: [http://plnkr.co/edit/N6xTrvLHWdOMG9Lq?open=lib%2Findex.html&preview]

Comment: Here the working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/N6xTrvLHWdOMG9Lq?open=lib%2Findex.html

Comment: Any idea why this example (see plunkr above) doesn't work offline (both html files downloaded and started on my desktop)? Tested with Firefox Version 76 and Chrome.

Comment: `$.load` is just a shorthand of the `jQuery.Ajax` function, it won't load local files from the filesystem. Maybe You need to try something like this: https://www.usbwebserver.net/webserver/